# Meu código esta apresentando o resultado errado e não faço ideia de como arrumar

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int GastoTotal;
    int frangos;
    int custo;
    
    custo <= 4,00+(3,50 * 2);
    
    
    printf("Informe o número de frangos\n");
    scanf("%d",&frangos);
    
    GastoTotal <= frangos * custo;
    
    printf("O seu Gasto Total será de %d",&GastoTotal);
}
```

esse é o código.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

É uma boa pratica inicializar as variáveis.
Para fazer uma atribuição use apenas `=` e não `<=`.
Para mostrar o valor em `printf` não use o `&`, ele representa o endereço de memoria da variável.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

int GastoTotal = 0;
int frangos = 0;
int custo = 4.00+(3.50 * 2);


printf("Informe o número de frangos\n");
scanf("%d",&frangos);

GastoTotal = frangos * custo;

printf("O seu Gasto Total será de %d", GastoTotal);
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. me ajudou muito.